# Spring.net SQL select a single value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, spring.net

Hey, is there a way using Spring.net to run a select query and have it return a single value.  If there is a way, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Spring .NET manipulates with data using both NHibernate and it's own DAO.
Sooo... If you're using Spring .NET DAO then you should use

```
ExecuteScalar method of DbCommand.
```

[More details.](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/data-quickstart.html)

If you're looking for NHibernate example, then you should use

```
UniqueResult method of IQuery
```

It should be something like this:

```
long veryImportantId = (long) session.GetNamedQuery("someQueryName").SetString("someParam", "someValue").UniqueResult();
```

I hope it helps you. If not, then please write slightly more details about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My best bet would be to use Query for a single object method available with spring.net.  You can learn more here: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/ado.html#ado-query-for-single-object